# How can I get breakpoints working in vscode using a devcontainer when my app is running inside another docker container on the host?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-devcontainer

So I have a devcontainer running in vscode, which is my dev env. It has the correct version of node etc.. so all devs are using the same version of node, npm etc..

We then run `docker-compose up` to start our app and a database. The app service has a volume map to the local directory so it picks up code changes made from inside vscode - so far so good.

But how do I now allow vscode to connect to that running instance of the app and stop on breakpoints?

This is a typescript nestjs app. We start it with `nest start --debug --watch` and it looks like it's listening:

```bash
exchange-be-uiapi    | Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/d68b4dad-6449-4380-9685-b9afb97b3a4a
exchange-be-uiapi    | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

And this is my launch.json:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach Exchange BE",
        "port": 9229,
        "restart": true
      }
    ]
  }
```

But when I start the debugger the progress bar starts for a few seconds then stops, there's no output that I can find so I don't know what the issue is.

The app docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  exchange-db:
    image: postgres:13.6
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: exchange-db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: exchange-db
      POSTGRES_DB: exchange-db
    volumes:
      - ./postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    container_name: exchange-db
    networks:
      - exchange-be-network
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  exchange-be-uiapi:
    container_name: exchange-be-uiapi
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      THALLO_START_MODE: uiapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - exchange-db
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
      - 9229:9229
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/thallo/exchange-be
    networks:
      - exchange-be-network  
# volumes:
  # exchange-be-volume:
  #   external: true
  # postgresdata:

networks:
  exchange-be-network:
    external: true
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common#_nodejs) helps?

Comment: @ikhvjs that doc is about launching a new instance of the app and attaching to it - I want to attach to an existing running instance. Which is what the "request": "attach", bit should do.

Comment: I see. I think you are looking for [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-node)